# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Give this error message when build android app in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am using qt 5.12 and when compile give this error message. I think it happen when download gradle 4.

Here is the detail error code:

```
Generating Android Package
  Input file: D:/PROJECTS/All Projects/Qt Projects/In Progress/build-Android_Test1-Android_Qt_5_12_10_Clang_armeabi_v7a-Debug/android-libAndroid_Test1.so-deployment-settings.json
  Output directory: D:/PROJECTS/All Projects/Qt Projects/In Progress/build-Android_Test1-Android_Qt_5_12_10_Clang_armeabi_v7a-Debug/android-build/
  Application binary: D:/PROJECTS/All Projects/Qt Projects/In Progress/build-Android_Test1-Android_Qt_5_12_10_Clang_armeabi_v7a-Debug/libAndroid_Test1.so
  Android build platform: android-32
  Install to device: No
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '17.0.1'.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  -- Skipping D:/PROJECTS/IDE/Qt5.12.10/5.12.10/android_armv7/plugins/iconengines/libqsvgicon.so. It has unmet dependencies: lib/libQt5Svg.so.
  -- Skipping D:/PROJECTS/IDE/Qt5.12.10/5.12.10/android_armv7/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so. It has unmet dependencies: lib/libQt5Svg.so.
Building the android package failed!
  -- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
17:20:14: The process "D:\PROJECTS\IDE\Qt5.12.10\5.12.10\android_armv7\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" exited with code 14.
Error while building/deploying project Android_Test1 (kit: Android Qt 5.12.10 Clang armeabi-v7a)
When executing step "Build Android APK"
17:20:14: Elapsed time: 00:17.
```